# Iam working on a GitHub code DatabaseManager_For_Android and I am getting error at the getActivity() method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a GitHub code DatabaseManager_For_Android on android studio and I am getting error at the `getActivity()` method. 
The error as following :

> Error:(40, 47) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

Any help please?

The code:

```
package com.example.toshiba.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_l);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_id);

        sButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent dbmanager = new Intent(getActivity(), AndroidDatabaseManager.class);
                startActivity(dbmanager);
            }
        });
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent dbmanager = new Intent(getActivity(), AndroidDatabaseManager.class);
                startActivity(dbmanager);
            }
        });
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);

// Inserting Shop/Rows
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addShop(new Shop("Dockers", " 475 Brannan St #330, San Francisco, CA 94107, United States"));
        db.addShop(new Shop("Dunkin Donuts", "White Plains, NY 10601"));
        db.addShop(new Shop("Pizza Porlar", "North West Avenue, Boston , USA"));
        db.addShop(new Shop("Town Bakers", "Beverly Hills, CA 90210, USA"));

// Reading all shops
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all shops..");
        List<Shop> shops = db.getAllShops();

        for (Shop shop : shops) {
            String log = "Id: " + shop.getId() + " ,Name: " + shop.getName() + " ,Address: " + shop.getAddress();
// Writing shops to log
            Log.d("Shop: : ", log);
        }

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.toshiba.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.toshiba.myapplication/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `getActivity()` defined?

Comment: sorry but I am not sure what you mean, can you pleas explain to me? i will be really thankful :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the method `getActivity()` with `this` or name of the Activity class: `MainActivity.this`

So the line becomes: 
`Intent dbmanager = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AndroidDatabaseManager.class);`

Comment: i tried replacing the getActivity() with this only before but didn't work out, however the second suggestion did work out :) thank you very much